# How to call a generic function without importing its file?

Tags: ksh

Assume I have a `function.ksh` file that contains a function called `getServerIp`. I don't want to create a new script file and import `function.ksh`, I just want to run `getServerIp` from my current shell. As far as I know this is not possible; is there some way I've missed?

Answer (score 4):

It's quite possible.

Create a directory (let's say `$HOME/functions`), and put your `getServerIp` function in a file called `getServerIp` in that directory. Make sure that file is executable.

Then all you need is to add `$HOME/functions` to your `$FPATH` environment variable and you're done - you can call `getServerIp` as if it was a built-in.

There are other options too. Please check out: [Korn Shell Functions](http://www.speakeasy.org/~arkay/216-7.4KshFunctions.html).

Comment: Well it is not quite what I want to do. Let s say there are several function like getServerIp, getVirtualIp, IsCluster etc. . The thing is they are all generic functions and they can be called when  I import function.ksh file on another script file. What I want is just run  IsCluster in command prompt. In the way you said, I should do the same settings for all functions in function.ksh. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: With what I wrote above, you don't need to import anything. All the functions you place in `FPATH` (in files with the same name as the function) get auto-imported in your shell. You can use them directly on the command line or in scripts without any other work.

Comment: Yes you are we dont need to import anything. However I don t want to add my function to a new file and add it to FPATH. I need a way to call my function a way like calling a method. For example is it possible to call the function as "function.ksh getSeverIp" . I hope it is not complicated and  I hope I explained myself. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: create symbolic link in yout FPATH folder to the file taht contain the function having the specific wanted function as name